# Javascript: calculating birth year

Tags: javascript

I created three prompt boxes to enter date, month and day. And I am trying to display birth year, next turning year and display days, hours, minutes, and seconds of next birthday. for that I created date object. calculating everything but I am not getting an answer. could  anyone help me ?

code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    p{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>lab14</title>


</head>
<body background= "lab14_images/birth.jpg">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: monospace;"> My age </h1>
    <p id="dateField"> </p>
    <p id="birthField"> </p>
    <p id="nextBirth"> </p>

    <script>    

        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];

        var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var today = new Date(); 
        var startDate = new Date();

        var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
        var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
        var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

        var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

        var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
        .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' 
        + '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';

        var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, myMonth, myDay);
        // !!! WHERE is startDate defined???
        var s = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000

        var nextBirth = document.getElementById("nextBirth").innerHTML = "I am" + endDate + "Years old, and will turn"+  endDate + 1  +"in:"+ days +"days," + hours +"hours" + minutes +"minutes" + seconds +"seconds"   ; 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed 1 error: moved assignment of value to `endDate` **before** it is actually used.

Please look at my `!!!` comment.  You are using a variable that you neither defined nor initialized.

Play with the snippet and pay attention to console errors in the right-bottom corner of the screen.

```js
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];

        var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var today = new Date(); 
        //var birth = new Date();

        var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
        var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
        var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

        var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

        var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
        .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' 
        + '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';

        var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, myMonth, myDay);
        // !!! WHERE is startDate defined???
        var secondsBetween = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000
        

        var seconds = Math.floor( (endDate/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (endDate/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (endDate/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( endDate/(1000*60*60*24) );

        var nextBirth = document.getElementById("nextBirth").innerHTML = "I am" + endDate + "Years old, and will turn"+  endDate + 1  +"in:"+ days +"days," + hours +"hours" + minutes +"minutes" + seconds +"seconds"   ;
```

```css
    p{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
  <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: monospace;"> My age </h1>
    <p id="dateField"> </p>
    <p id="birthField"> </p>
    <p id="nextBirth"> </p>
```

Comment: Do you actually understand **your** code? What is `secondsBetween` variable for?

Comment: That is just variable name I have given in order to calculate birth year. I changed name of it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to make this code working ?

Comment: I do not care about its name. Where do you use it?

Comment: Start debugging it and verify every value along the way whether it matches your expectations.